# Storing stylus in JSON / Document database

Tags: json, node.js, arangodb, stylus

I want to store Stylus in JSON, so it would look something like:

```
{
  "file": "main",
  "content:" "body
                  font: 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

              a.button
                  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                  border-radius: 5px;"
}
```

but I understand that its impossible to store with out using the /n is there any way I can format the tabbing / identation automatically so it can be stored and retrieved from a document database i.e. MongoDB or ArangoDB.

Comment: Just use \n for new lines  and \t for tabs `"body\n\tfont: 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n\na.button\n\t-webkit-border-radius: 5px;\n\t-moz-border-radius: 5px;\n\tborder-radius: 5px;"`

Comment: @Molda I heard of this approach, say if I had the file main.stylus, how would I programmatically convert it to the said format to be stored in a database, as it isn't really convenient to write stylus in that format.

Comment: Well, the escape characters (\n, \t, etc.) are invisible but they are there. To prove it to you you can try this: create your stylus file with new lines and tabs and save it. Then read it with `fs.readFile('filename.stylus', 'utf8', function(err, data) {` and try to split the data by `\t` and you get an array. This means the `\t`'s are there but invisible. Hope it makes sense :) Also this means if you save the file content to a db and later retrieve it and save it back to file then the tabs and new lines will still be there.

Comment: @Molda thanks for the help, I've figured it out and posted an answer, I used your method and works great! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example storing the content of a file as string attribute value, without RegExp or the like (no processing of input data, it is already a UTF-8 string):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const arangojs = require('arangojs');
const aql = arangojs.aql;

// Const variables for connecting to ArangoDB database
const host = '127.0.0.1'
const port = '8529'
const username = 'root' // default user
const password = '' // blank password by default
const database = '_system' // default database

 // Connection to ArangoDB
db = new arangojs.Database({
    url: `http://${host}:${port}`,
    databaseName: database
});
db.useBasicAuth(username, password); // authenticate

fs.readFile('assets/total.styl', 'utf-8', (error, content) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    db.query(aql`
        INSERT {
            name: "Total",
            type: "stylus",
            content: ${content}
        } INTO stylesheets
        RETURN NEW
    `).then(
        cursor => cursor.all()
    ).then(
        docs => docs.forEach(doc => console.log(doc)),
        err => console.error('Query failed:\n', err.response.body)
    );
});
```

Resulting document (system attributes left out):

```
{
  "name": "Total",
  "type": "stylus",
  "content": "{\r\n  \"file\": \"main\",\r\n  \"content:\" \"body\r\n                  font: 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\r\n\r\n              a.button\r\n                  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;\r\n                  -moz-border-radius: 5px;\r\n                  border-radius: 5px;\"\r\n}"
}
```

To quote the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> **2.5.  Strings**
>
> The representation of strings is
>   similar to conventions used in the C
>   family of programming languages.  A
>   string begins and ends with quotation
>   marks.  All Unicode characters may be
>   placed within the quotation marks
>   except for the characters that must be
>   escaped: quotation mark, reverse
>   solidus, and the control characters
>   (U+0000 through U+001F).
>
> Any character *may* be escaped.

If your .styl file contained such characters...

`00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 5C 11 12 22 13`

they would end up encoded properly in the document:

```
{
  "name": "Total",
  "type": "stylus",
  "content": "\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\t\u0010\\\u0011\u0012\"\u0013"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after some extensive research I found out for ArangoDB, you can do the following:

```
var removeSpace = content.replace(new RegExp(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, 'g'), '\n')
```

**and remember no need to escape the \n**,
for other databases this isn't necessary as those databases automatically do the JSON.stringify the values passed.

An example: (assuming the DB variable holds the Database connection)

```
import IO from 'fs'
IO.readFile('assets/total.styl', 'utf8', function(error, content) {
  if(error) {
    throw error
  }
  var contentUpdated = content.replace(new RegExp(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, 'g'), '\n')
  console.log(contentUpdated)

  cursor = DB.query('INSERT { name: "Total",  type: "stylus", content: "' + contentUpdated + '"} INTO stylesheets RETURN NEW').then(
    console.log(cursor)
  )

})
```

In the end, as mentioned you don't need to replace anything, ArangoDB did it automatically for me.

Comment: What driver do you use to interact with ArangoDB?

Comment: @CoDEmanX I use https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs or if there is a need for a schema / ORM I go for https://www.npmjs.com/package/caminte